# PHP Regex for IMDB/TMDB Urls

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a code what compares a links from imdb and tmdb. 
The code matches link to imdb and then transforms it for the tmdb link, if was inserted.

The links look like:
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228
https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/24428

I want to ask if these regexs are correct for movies links.

For ex.

```
$imdb_url =  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228

            if (strpos($imdb_url, 'themoviedb.org') == true) {
                preg_match_all('/\\d*-/', $imdb_url, $tmdb_id);

                $tmdb_id        = $tmdb_id[0];
                $tmdb_id        = str_replace('-', '', $tmdb_id);
                $tmdb_id        = $tmdb_id[0];

                $request_url    = amy_movie_provider_build_query_url('tmdb', $tmdb_id, $api_key);
                $the_data       = wp_remote_get($request_url, array(
                    'timeout'     => $timeout,
                ));

                if (!is_wp_error($the_data) && !empty($the_data)) {
                    $movie_data = json_decode($the_data['body'], true);
                    $result     = amy_movie_add_tmdb_movie_data($movie_data);

                    echo $result;
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $result     = esc_html__('Provider TMDB being error!', 'amy-movie-extend');

                    echo $result;
                    exit;
                }

                exit;
            }
```

And else for imdb link:

```
else if (strpos($imdb_url, 'www.imdb.com') == true) {
                preg_match_all('/tt\\d{7}/', $imdb_url, $imdb_id);

                $imdb_id    = $imdb_id[0];
                $imdb_id    = $imdb_id[0];
            }
```

I think it's not working because something may be wrong with not existing /movie prefix in the link, but I tried changing that and it still catches error 404.

Comment: `preg_match_all('/tt\\d{7}/', $imdb_url, $imdb_id);` <-- one backslash too much.

Comment: No, '\\' perfectly escapes the backslash in the string context, so it's more correct than only having one for the regex itself.

@Dominik please give examples on non-working URLs.

Comment: @AmigoJack I wrote a examples of non-working urls at the beginning of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combining the domain part with the rest of the URI? Why once omitting the subdomain and once making it mandatory?

```
$sURI= 'whatever';
if( preg_match( '#imdb\\.com/title/tt(\\d{7})#i', $sURI, $aMatch ) ) {
  echo 'IMDb, movie #'. $aMatch[1];
} else
if( preg_match( '#themoviedb.org/movie/(\\d+)($|-)#i', $sURI, $aMatch ) ) {
  echo 'TMDb, movie #'. $aMatch[1];
} else {
  echo 'Unrecognized';
}
```

This way it doesn't matter if the IMDb URI comes with `www.` or not. Since the movie IDs have a fixed length we don't even need to expect/care a slash following. Your mistake was expecting a slash without any need.

Same for TMDb, which either ends right away (but we want to get all digits to the end, not just the first) or is followed by a dash. `i` is for really distorted URIs for whichever reason. Your mistake was to expect a dash and to make digits entirely optional (when at least one should be needed, as in https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/9)

Side note: Using `\\d` in a PHP string for a regular expression is the correct way, as you first have to deal with the string context - there an effective backslash has to be escaped by the backslash itself. And only after that the scope of the regular expression is encountered. `\d` only also works because unknown string escapings are silently ignored.